# SharePoint2010 to SharePoint 2013 - just the lists and content types

Tags: 2013, 2010, content-type, upgrade, large-lists

Hi I'm trying to upgrade my SP2010 site to SP2013 but ideally I just want to take the 'content' of the site so, documents, lists, content types and perhaps user permissions (although I could recreate these).

The SP2010 site has lots of features and solutions that were used to deploy the lists as well as 'frontend' changes to the SharePoint experience.

I just want to ditch all the features and solutions and focus on the content - there will be changes and redevelopments of these features so that's ok.

I've tried to export and import the lists but this seems to break the connection between the documents and the content types.

I've tried database backup/restore/upgrade but this seems to have brought along a few 'requirements' to features and solutions that don't exist and now are playing hell with the sharepoint site.

I've given https://github.com/achimismaili/featureadmin a go but Alas this doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

Currently it seems I might be looking down the barrel of a csom export/import solution which might take ages (there is alot of data) to complete.

Is there anything else that I'm missing and can look into.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the content, then you need to use a 3rd party tool. My personal favorite is Sharegate, but there are others out there from Metalogix, AvePoint, and so forth.

Comment: Don't all these just use some powershell commands to get what you want?

Comment: No, but they do use the SharePoint API.

Comment: So isn't that just like a csom solution?

Comment: Sharegate is CSOM out of the box but has an SSOM extension. If you feel you can develop a migration app for less than a few $k, then purchasing a migration app wouldn't make financial sense.

Comment: So does Sharegate take some time to upgrade a large site say with a content database of 5GB?

Comment: Sharegate does not upgrade databases. It is a content migration tool. You connect to the source and target then copy the content you want. If you want to do a content database attach upgrade, you do not need 3rd party tools.